# Inserting multiple rows with Merge NOT MATCHED

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

```
MERGE tbl_target t
USING tbl_source s
ON t.itemnum = s.itemnum
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    INSERT (itemnum, minqty, maxqty, parent)
    VALUES (s.itemnum,0,99,10),(s.itemnum,0,99,80);
```

I'm trying to Insert two rows on the target table if an item does not exist on target but does exist on the source. Everytime I try SQL server gives an error on the ',' between the VALUES.

*A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;)*

Is it possible to do multi-row inserts in a MERGE statement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible by tweaking the `USING` clause to return multiple rows per `tbl_source.itemnum` value:

```
MERGE tbl_target t
USING (
  select s.itemnum, 
         0 as minqty, 
         99 as maxqty,
         p.parent 
    from tbl_source s
    cross join (
      select 10 as parent
      union all
      select 80 as parent) p
) s
ON t.itemnum = s.itemnum
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (itemnum, minqty, maxqty, parent)
    VALUES (s.itemnum,s.minqty,s.maxqty,s.parent);
```

Comment: Worked, not sure if i'm going to keep the solution or not as it makes quite a mess when trying on the real tables with many more columns, but this is definitely a correct solution to my problem. 

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What I understand from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) is that you can only insert a row for each non matching record. Do you need to use Merge? If not the following will work

```
WITH CTE (Sitemnum) 
AS 
(
    SELECT s.itemnum
    FROM tbl_source s
    LEFT JOIN tbl_target t ON (s.itemnum = t.itemnum)
    WHERE t.itemnum IS NULL
)
INSERT tbl_target
SELECT Sitemnum,0,99,10 
FROM CTE
UNION 
SELECT Sitemnum,0,99,80
FROM CTE
```